# Opening certain PDFs on iOS causes Safari / iBooks to crash or display an error

Tags: ios, pdf, safari

Opening certain PDFs on iOS causes Safari / iBooks to crash or display an error.

> A problem repeatedly occurred on "*url*"

Opening these same PDFs used to work fine so I'm not sure if it's due to an iOS update, or the software that's generating the PDFs.

Interestingly if I use my Mac (using Preview) and open one of these PDFs and delete 1 page, the file size goes from about 60MB down to 14MB, and then the file opens fine on iOS.

This led me to think that maybe it was a file size issue, but I have some other documents that are over 100MB that open fine.

I tried using PDFINFO to see if I could see any differences between the original and the one where I deleted 1 page, and all I can see is that one is PDF version 1.6 and the modified one becomes version 1.3

Are there any tools that could do a more in-depth analysis to see A) what's wrong with the original version, or B) what's different between the original and the one where I delete 1 page and re-save?

Anyone else experiencing similar problems?

Comment: This remains an issue as of late 2020. Any ideas, anyone?